# Is the function $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^\omega$ defined by $f(t) = (t, t, t, \ldots)$ continuous in the uniform topology?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Can someone please verify my proof or offer suggestions for improvement? I am aware that there is a similar question elsewhere, but I need help with my proof in particular.

Notation used:

Countably infinite cartesian product of $\mathbb{R}$ with itself$: \ \ \ \ \mathbb{R}^\omega$

Uniform metric on $\mathbb{R}^\omega: \ \ \ \ \bar \rho (x, y) = \operatorname{sup}\{\bar d(x_i, y_i): i \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Standard metric on $\mathbb{R}: \ \ \ \ d(x, y)$

> Is the function $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^\omega$ defined by $f(t) = (t, t, t, \ldots)$ continuous in the uniform topology on $\mathbb{R}^\omega$?

No. Consider the point $x = (x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ defined by
$ x_k = \begin{cases} 
      -1 + \frac{1}{k-1} & k \ \ is \ \ even \\
      1-\frac{1}{k} & k \ \ is \ \ odd
   \end{cases}$

Consider the basis element of the uniform topology $B = B_\bar \rho (x, 1)$. Suppose $y \in  f^{-1}(B)$. Then, $f(y) \in B$. This implies that $d(x_k, y) < 1$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. That is, $|x_k-y| < 1$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Clearly, it must be the case that $y=0$.

But $f^{-1}(B) = \{0\}$ is not open under the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $f$ is not continuous in the uniform topology.

Comment: It works (I think)? What exactly do you want us to help you with?

Comment: Are you sure $\overline\rho$ is a metric? What is $\rho((n),(0))$?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what he means by $\bar d$? Maybe that means some bounded metric, like $\bar d(x,y)=\left|\arctan x-\arctan y\right|$. @AsafKaragila

Comment: @Asaf: From another of the OP’s questions it’s a fairly safe bet that $\overline{d}(x,y)=\min\{1,|x-y|\}$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the map $f$ **is** continuous, assuming that $\overline{d}(x,y)=\min\{1,|x-y|\}$ for $x,y\in\Bbb R$. Let $\Delta=f[\Bbb R]$; it suffices to show that if $x\in\Delta$ and $r>0$, then $f^{-1}[B(x,r)]$ is open in $\Bbb R$. Let $x\in\Delta$ and $r>0$; there is some $t\in\Bbb R$ such that $x=\langle t,t,t,\ldots\rangle$. There are now two cases.

1. If $r>1$, show that $f^{-1}[B(x,r)]=\Bbb R$.
2. If $r\le 1$, show that $f^{-1}[B(x,r)]=(t-r,t+r)$.

In each case $f^{-1}[B(x,r)]$ is open in $\Bbb R$, so $f$ is continuous. (In fact $f$ is a homeomorphism between $\Bbb R$ and $\Delta$.)

Another way to look at all this is to notice that for any $s,t\in\Bbb R$, $$\overline\rho\left(f(s),f(t)\right)=\overline d(s,t)\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

You only showed that $f^{-1}(B)\subset\{0\}$.
But since $f(0)=0\notin B$, you have $f^{-1}(B)=\emptyset$ which is open.

Your function $f$ is indeed continuous since it is isometric.

Comment: We cannot say $f$ is "isometric" unless we know $d = \overline{d}$, and then $\overline{\rho}$ is not a metric...

Comment: @GEdgar, I understood implicitly from the question that $d=\bar d$ and that the question is only about the subspace $X=\{x\in\mathbb R^\omega;\bar\rho(x,0)<\infty\}\subset\mathbb R^\omega$. user154185, did you mean this or something else?

Comment: No, $d$ is not $\overline{d}$. However, $f$ is an isometry from $\langle\Bbb R,\overline{d}\rangle$ onto the diagonal in $\langle\Bbb R^\omega,\overline{\rho}\rangle$, where $\overline{d}$ is as in my comment under the original question.